# Text is not centered

Tags: horizontal-alignment

The issue is that the text is not getting centered even after issueing `\centering`. The following picture depicts it : 
[image] 
The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{wedn}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
{\newgeometry{margin=1in, centering}
\noindent \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
{\LARGE\centering\bfseries MATERIAL SCIENCE \par}
\noindent \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
{\wedn\large\centering {Department of Physics\par Pondicherry Engineering College}}
}
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

Comment: Put `\centering` in place of `\noindent` and remove it from the other places.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Less is more. You want all elements of your title page to be centered, so issue `\centering` at the top level.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{wedn} %<-------- ARE YOU REALLY SURE?

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{margin=1in, centering}
\centering

\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}

\LARGE\textbf{MATERIAL SCIENCE}

\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}

\large\wedn Department of Physics\\ Pondicherry Engineering College

\end{titlepage}

\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the big text to be vertically centered between the rules, a lower level command is better:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{margin=1in, centering}
\centering

\hrule height 2pt \vspace{3pt}

\LARGE\textbf{MATERIAL SCIENCE}

\vspace{3pt}\hrule height 2pt

\medskip

\wedn\large Department of Physics\\ Pondicherry Engineering College

\end{titlepage}
```

[image]

Change the spacing to suit.

Answer (score 3):

TeX uses the setting that is active at the *end* of the paragraph.

```
 {\wedn\large\centering Department of Physics\par Pondicherry Engineering College}% removed non-functional braces
```

The first "Department of Physics" is centered, because `\centering` is active, `\par` is inside the group. But "Pondicherry Engineering College" is using the setting before the group, i.e. not `\centering`.

Solution: Add `\par` explicitly:

```
{\wedn\large\centering Department of Physics\par Pondicherry Engineering College\par}
```

As alternative `\centering` can be put at the start of the `titlepage` environment as in egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176975/16967), if all elements of the environment should be horizontally centered.

### Vertical centering of text between lines

In [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15500788#15500788) the question about vertical centering of the head line arised.
Modifying egreg's example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{wedn}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{margin=1in, centering}
\centering

\LARGE
\hrule height 2pt\relax
\kern1ex
\centerline{\textbf{MATERIAL SCIENCE}}
\kern1ex
\hrule height 2pt\relax

\vspace{1ex}

\large\wedn
Department of Physics\\[.5ex]
Pondicherry Engineering College

\end{titlepage}

\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

It is using plain TeX syntax here (`\hrule`, `\centerline`) rather than LaTeX, because it is a more direct approach. LaTeX always wants to start a new paragraph, which is not needed here.

A "pure LaTeX" solution is

```
\renewcommand*{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
\hline
\rule{0pt}{1ex}\tabularnewline
\centering\bfseries MATERIAL SCIENCE\tabularnewline
\rule{0pt}{1ex}\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular*}
```