# Alignment within tex groups

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Please consider the following snippet:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
%\begingroup
\centering
Text

\begin{tabular}{ll}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{tabular}
%\endgroup
\end{document}
```

I have been doing LaTeX for a while now, but I cannot figure out why in the
code above, everything gets layed out using `\centering` (as expected).
But when I introduce a new group using `\begingroup` or `\bgroup`, only `Text` is centered (just remove the `%` signs). Quite puzzling.

Comment: Just an an implicit paragraph break (e.g., an empty line) or an explicit paragraph break (e.g., `\par`) between `\end{tabular}` and `\endgroup`, and the `tabular` environment will be typeset centered as well.

Comment: As your code stands, the paragraph  containing the `tabular` environment ends _after_ the `\endgroup`; therefore, it is typeset with `\centering` no longer in force.

Comment: This is very similar in nature to [Text is not centered](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176969/5764).

Comment: Please, don't use the `minimal` class; it's not meant for minimal examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\centering` in LaTeX is obtained by setting `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` to infinitely stretchable glue (while, on the other hand, setting `\parfillskip` to zero).

`\leftskip` and `\rightskip` specify glue that TeX should insert at the left, resp. right, of every line of a paragraph when the paragraph itself is broken into lines; since this happens when the `\par` token is digested, and since TeX uses for the whole paragraph the value of `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` which is in force at that time, it is essential that the `\par` token is found at the same (or inner) grouping level as the one in which `\centering` is being issued.  A common mistake is to end a group prematurely, when, in TeX's eyes, the paragraph has not yet ended, because no empty line has been read yet.

Btw, `\centering` also zeroes the paragraph indentation; but since the indentation is contributed to the horizontal list into which the contents of the paragraph are temporarily saved as soon as the paragraph begins, in a situation like the one presented in the question the paragraph will not be indented, even if it is not going to be centered.